# How to enlarge the font in the bottom window in VS?

Tags: visual-studio

Does anyone know how can I enlarge the font in the window of VS,
this one who contains the Output, Bookmarks, FindResults etc.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings for these can be found in Tools => Options; Environment, Font and Colors. On the top "Show settings for" has the different tool windows, e.g. "Find Results Window", or "All Text Tool Windows" (probably for everything that doesn't have their own settings).

The remaining tool windows seem to be affected by "Environment" under "Show settings for", by selecting a font other than "Automatic" and then setting the font size.

Comment: thank you but it didn't change windows like bookmarks or error list

Comment: @NissimLevy I amended my answer